# Ideal norm is completely multiplicative

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, ideals

Let $K$ be a number field and $\mathcal{O}_K$ be the ring of integers of $K$. For a non-zero ideal $\mathfrak{a}$ in $\mathcal{O}_K$, the norm $N(\mathfrak{a})$ is defined as the cardinality of quotient ring $\mathcal{O}_K / \mathfrak{a}$ , that is $N(\mathfrak{a}) = |\mathcal{O}_K / \mathfrak{a}|$.

I showed that $N(\mathfrak{p}^n) = N(\mathfrak{p})^n$ for all $n \geq 1$. I also know that $\mathcal{O}_K$ is a Dedekind domain. Thus, every non-zero ideal can be written uniquely as a product of prime ideals.

Now, I want to prove that norm is a completely multiplicative function. That is,
$$
N(\mathfrak{a}\mathfrak{b}) = N(\mathfrak{a})N(\mathfrak{b})
$$
for any ideals $\mathfrak{a}, \mathfrak{b}$ in $\mathcal{O}_K$.

Comment: All that's left is to check the case of relatively prime ideals.  That's just the Chinese remainder theorem: the ring $\mathcal O_K/\mathfrak a\mathfrak b$ is isomorphic to $\mathcal O_K/\mathfrak a \times \mathcal O_K/\mathfrak b$  when the ideals $\mathfrak a$ and $\mathfrak b$ are relatively prime.  Therefore the norm of the product is the product of the norms.

Comment: Or see Theorem 7.5 of https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/blurbs/gradnumthy/idealfactor.pdf, which proves multiplicativity without having to separately treat prime power ideals and relatively prime ideals.

Comment: Note that in $\Bbb{Z}[2i]$ the norm of $(2,2i)$ is $2$ and the norm of $(2,2i)^2 = (4,4i)$ is $8$, so $N(\mathfrak{p}^n) = N(\mathfrak{p})^n$ depends on Dedekind-domain-ness and is not trivial.